# apply() function uses character argument and refuses to execute if statement

Tags: r

I've been fighting this for some hours now. My code is below, It executes it as I want when I use a `for` loop, but as soon as I change to an `apply` function it breaks.

The issue is that my apply function refuses to generate a `FALSE (0)` or `TRUE (1)` signal for cases where `EMA_30` < `EMA_60`.

First, the issue seemed to be that apply casts all values to character modes due to my `Index` column. But changing the mode to numeric does not help either, what is the issue?

Code & Data

```
library(dplyr)    
StrategyDefine <- function(df) {
      # define strategy for buy and sell signal here

        buySignal <-  TRUE
        df <- select(df, -Index)
        df <- apply(df, 1, FUN = function(x) {

          if(x['EMASignal'] == 1 & buySignal == TRUE) {
           buySignal <- FALSE 
          }
          if(buySignal == FALSE) {
           x['Signal'] <- 1 
          } else { x['Signal'] <- 0 }

          if(buySignal == FALSE & x['EMA_30'] < x['EMA_60']) { # problem arises with this if statement. 
            x['Signal'] <- 0
            buySignal <- TRUE
          }
          x['buySignal'] <- buySignal

        ; 
          x['Signal']
        })
        return(as.numeric(df))
    } 

    > Data
                     Index   Open   High    Low  Close Volume Adj.Close     EMA_2   EMA_30   EMA_60  dailyChange EMASignal
            1   2007-08-08 165.50 167.00 163.00 167.00  40800    137.91 136.88738 141.0632 142.2844  0.009063444         0
            2   2007-08-09 168.50 169.00 163.00 167.00  45800    137.91 137.56913 140.8598 142.1409 -0.008902077         0
            3   2007-08-10 165.00 165.00 161.00 164.00  93400    135.43 136.14304 140.5095 141.9209 -0.006060606         0
            4   2007-08-13 166.00 169.00 163.00 163.00  41500    134.60 135.11435 140.1282 141.6809 -0.018072289         0
            5   2007-08-14 161.50 165.00 161.50 162.00  24700    133.78 134.22478 139.7187 141.4218  0.003095975         0
            6   2007-08-15 161.00 161.00 150.50 151.50  56800    125.11 128.14826 138.7762 140.8870 -0.059006211         0
            7   2007-08-16 149.75 150.00 146.00 147.00  68400    121.39 123.64275 137.6545 140.2478 -0.018363940         0
            8   2007-08-17 148.50 149.00 143.75 145.75  62800    120.36 121.45425 136.5387 139.5957 -0.018518519         0
            9   2007-08-20 146.75 150.00 146.00 146.00  26800    120.57 120.86475 135.5085 138.9719 -0.005110733         0
            10  2007-08-21 146.50 146.75 141.25 142.75  43000    117.88 118.87492 134.3712 138.2804 -0.025597270         0
            11  2007-08-22 143.50 145.75 143.25 144.00  40800    118.91 118.89831 133.3737 137.6453  0.003484321         0
            12  2007-08-23 145.75 152.00 145.50 152.00  52600    125.52 123.31277 132.8670 137.2477  0.042881647         0
            13  2007-08-24 149.00 153.00 148.25 152.50  27100    125.93 125.05759 132.4194 136.8767  0.023489933         0
            14  2007-08-27 154.50 157.50 150.00 151.00  37300    124.69 124.81253 131.9208 136.4771 -0.022653722         0
            15  2007-08-28 152.50 152.50 148.50 148.75  24400    122.84 123.49751 131.3349 136.0300 -0.024590164         0
            16  2007-08-29 148.25 154.50 148.00 153.00  59200    126.35 125.39917 131.0133 135.7126  0.032040472         0
            17  2007-08-30 153.00 155.00 151.50 153.00  80600    126.35 126.03306 130.7124 135.4056  0.000000000         0
            18  2007-08-31 155.50 155.50 151.50 153.00  41000    126.35 126.24435 130.4310 135.1087 -0.016077170         0
            19  2007-09-03 153.00 156.00 151.50 153.50  49500    126.76 126.58812 130.1942 134.8350  0.003267974         0
            20  2007-09-04 154.00 154.50 153.50 154.00  27900    127.17 126.97604 129.9990 134.5837  0.000000000         0
            21  2007-09-05 152.00 154.50 152.00 153.00  37300    126.35 126.55868 129.7636 134.3137  0.006578947         0
            22  2007-09-06 153.50 153.50 151.00 152.50  46500    125.93 126.13956 129.5163 134.0389 -0.006514658         0
            23  2007-09-07 151.50 153.00 145.00 147.50  41500    121.80 123.24652 129.0185 133.6376 -0.026402640         0
            24  2007-09-10 147.50 151.50 142.50 145.25  33500    119.95 121.04884 128.4334 133.1888 -0.015254237         0
            25  2007-09-11 146.50 149.75 145.75 145.75  25400    120.36 120.58961 127.9125 132.7682 -0.005119454         0
            26  2007-09-12 148.50 148.50 145.50 148.00 151500    122.22 121.67654 127.5453 132.4223 -0.003367003         0
            27  2007-09-13 148.00 150.00 147.00 148.25  34200    122.42 122.17218 127.2146 132.0944  0.001689189         0
            28  2007-09-14 149.25 150.00 145.00 145.75  23400    120.36 120.96406 126.7724 131.7097 -0.023450586         0
            29  2007-09-17 147.00 147.00 143.50 143.50  42000    118.50 119.32135 126.2387 131.2766 -0.023809524         0
            30  2007-09-18 145.50 148.00 143.75 145.00  10700    119.74 119.60045 125.8194 130.8983 -0.003436426         0
            31  2007-09-19 148.00 148.50 145.50 147.00  48100    121.39 120.79348 125.5336 130.5866 -0.006756757         0
            32  2007-09-20 147.50 148.25 144.00 148.00  38900    122.22 121.74449 125.3199 130.3123  0.003389831         0
            33  2007-09-21 148.50 148.50 144.25 146.75  56800    121.18 121.36816 125.0528 130.0128 -0.011784512         0
            34  2007-09-24 147.00 147.00 144.75 145.00  20800    119.74 120.28272 124.7100 129.6760 -0.013605442         0
            35  2007-09-25 147.50 147.50 144.75 145.00  30500    119.74 119.92091 124.3894 129.3502 -0.016949153         0
            36  2007-09-26 145.25 148.75 145.00 148.75  28900    122.84 121.86697 124.2894 129.1368  0.024096386         0
            37  2007-09-27 149.00 150.50 147.25 149.25  43400    123.25 122.78899 124.2223 128.9438  0.001677852         0
            38  2007-09-28 152.00 152.00 148.50 151.00  42600    124.69 124.05633 124.2525 128.8043 -0.006578947         0
            39  2007-10-01 151.00 151.50 149.50 150.50  32200    124.28 124.20544 124.2543 128.6560 -0.003311258         0
            40  2007-10-02 152.00 152.00 146.25 146.75  88700    121.18 122.18848 124.0560 128.4109 -0.034539474         0
            41  2007-10-03 149.50 149.50 144.00 144.50  54400    119.33 120.28283 123.7511 128.1131 -0.033444816         0
            42  2007-10-04 144.75 145.00 142.50 144.25  23200    119.12 119.50761 123.4523 127.8183 -0.003454231         0
            43  2007-10-05 145.75 146.00 144.25 145.50  10400    120.15 119.93587 123.2392 127.5669 -0.001715266         0
            44  2007-10-08 146.50 147.00 145.50 147.00   6000    121.39 120.90529 123.1199 127.3643  0.003412969         0
            45  2007-10-09 145.50 149.75 145.50 146.25 143900    120.77 120.81510 122.9683 127.1481  0.005154639         0
            46  2007-10-10 147.00 149.00 147.00 147.25  28800    121.60 121.33837 122.8800 126.9662  0.001700680         0
            47  2007-10-11 147.50 149.25 145.50 148.00  41100    122.22 121.92612 122.8375 126.8106  0.003389831         0
            48  2007-10-12 148.00 149.75 148.00 149.75 149800    123.66 123.08204 122.8905 126.7073  0.011824324         0
            49  2007-10-15 150.00 150.50 148.50 149.25  35200    123.25 123.19401 122.9137 126.5940 -0.005000000         0
            50  2007-10-16 151.00 151.00 146.00 147.50  32000    121.80 122.26467 122.8419 126.4368 -0.023178808         0
            51  2007-10-17 147.50 148.50 145.75 148.50  21200    122.63 122.50822 122.8282 126.3120  0.006779661         0
            52  2007-10-18 149.00 149.25 146.50 148.50  36100    122.63 122.58941 122.8154 126.1912 -0.003355705         0
            53  2007-10-19 149.75 149.75 148.25 149.00  64300    123.04 122.88980 122.8299 126.0879 -0.005008347         0
            54  2007-10-22 148.00 149.00 146.00 147.50 101300    121.80 122.16327 122.7634 125.9473 -0.003378378         0
            55  2007-10-23 147.00 149.50 147.00 149.00 139200    123.04 122.74776 122.7813 125.8520  0.013605442         0
            56  2007-10-24 147.50 148.75 145.00 147.00  36400    121.39 121.84259 122.6915 125.7057 -0.003389831         0
            57  2007-10-25 147.25 148.75 147.00 148.00  19400    122.22 122.09420 122.6611 125.5914  0.005093379         0
            58  2007-10-26 146.50 147.25 145.50 147.25  17800    121.60 121.76473 122.5927 125.4606  0.005119454         0
            59  2007-10-29 148.00 148.00 146.00 146.75  30300    121.18 121.37491 122.5015 125.3202 -0.008445946         0
            60  2007-10-30 147.25 148.00 145.75 146.75 282500    121.18 121.24497 122.4163 125.1845 -0.003395586         0
            61  2007-10-31 147.75 149.50 147.50 149.00  25300    123.04 122.44166 122.4565 125.1142  0.008460237         0
            62  2007-11-01 149.50 152.00 146.00 147.00 251100    121.39 121.74055 122.3877 124.9921 -0.016722408         0
            63  2007-11-02 148.75 148.75 145.75 146.75  28400    121.18 121.36685 122.3098 124.8671 -0.013445378         0
            64  2007-11-05 145.50 146.75 140.50 141.75 163400    117.06 118.49562 121.9711 124.6111 -0.025773196         0
            65  2007-11-06 143.50 144.00 141.50 142.00  21300    117.26 117.67187 121.6671 124.3701 -0.010452962         0
            66  2007-11-07 142.50 143.50 138.25 143.25 174500    118.29 118.08396 121.4493 124.1707  0.005263158         0
            67  2007-11-08 138.50 145.25 138.50 144.25  92500    119.12 118.77465 121.2990 124.0051  0.041516245         0
            68  2007-11-09 148.50 148.50 145.00 145.25 121700    119.95 119.55822 121.2120 123.8722 -0.021885522         0
            69  2007-11-12 145.25 146.00 143.50 145.50  53800    120.15 119.95274 121.1434 123.7501  0.001721170         0
            70  2007-11-13 144.50 149.00 144.50 148.75 146900    122.84 121.87758 121.2529 123.7203  0.029411765         0
            71  2007-11-14 150.00 154.50 148.50 151.50 129600    125.11 124.03253 121.5017 123.7659  0.010000000         0
            72  2007-11-15 150.50 152.00 147.25 149.00  31100    123.04 123.37084 121.6010 123.7421 -0.009966777         0
            73  2007-11-16 149.00 150.00 146.25 149.75 117000    123.66 123.56361 121.7338 123.7394  0.005033557         0
            74  2007-11-19 149.00 150.50 148.00 149.50  70700    123.46 123.49454 121.8452 123.7302  0.003355705         0
            75  2007-11-20 148.25 151.50 148.25 150.50  71400    124.28 124.01818 122.0023 123.7482  0.015177066         0
            76  2007-11-21 151.00 154.00 149.00 150.50 386000    124.28 124.19273 122.1492 123.7657 -0.003311258         0
            77  2007-11-22 150.50 150.50 144.75 144.75 139800    119.53 121.08424 121.9802 123.6268 -0.038205980         0
            78  2007-11-23 146.25 146.25 142.75 144.75 126400    119.53 120.04808 121.8222 123.4925 -0.010256410         0
            79  2007-11-26 144.50 147.50 142.75 144.00  48600    118.91 119.28936 121.6343 123.3422 -0.003460208         0
            80  2007-11-27 142.00 145.50 142.00 143.50  37000    118.50 118.76312 121.4321 123.1835  0.010563380         0
            81  2007-11-28 145.00 146.00 142.00 146.00  38600    120.57 119.96771 121.3765 123.0978  0.006896552         0
            82  2007-11-29 146.75 153.50 146.50 149.25 268500    123.25 122.15590 121.4973 123.1028  0.017035775         0
            83  2007-11-30 153.00 153.00 149.00 152.00  71800    125.52 124.39863 121.7569 123.1820 -0.006535948         0
            84  2007-12-03 148.25 150.00 148.25 150.00  38600    123.87 124.04621 121.8932 123.2046  0.011804384         0
            85  2007-12-04 148.00 148.50 139.50 142.75 205600    117.88 119.93540 121.6343 123.0300 -0.035472973         0
            86  2007-12-05 143.75 146.00 141.75 143.75 111800    118.71 119.11847 121.4456 122.8884  0.000000000         0
            87  2007-12-06 144.50 145.25 142.50 145.25  42800    119.95 119.67282 121.3491 122.7920  0.005190311         0
            88  2007-12-07 144.00 147.00 144.00 145.50 121900    120.15 119.99094 121.2718 122.7054  0.010416667         0
            89  2007-12-10 144.00 149.50 144.00 148.75  88000    122.84 121.89031 121.3729 122.7098  0.032986111         0
            90  2007-12-11 148.50 150.50 148.00 150.50  51800    124.28 123.48344 121.5605 122.7613  0.013468013         0
            91  2007-12-12 148.25 149.00 147.50 148.00  21500    122.22 122.64115 121.6030 122.7436 -0.001686341         0
            92  2007-12-13 148.00 149.00 145.00 147.50  39300    121.80 122.08038 121.6157 122.7126 -0.003378378         0
            93  2007-12-14 146.75 147.50 144.50 144.50  40400    119.33 120.24679 121.4683 122.6017 -0.015332198         0
            94  2007-12-17 144.00 144.00 139.00 139.00  57000    114.78 116.60226 121.0368 122.3453 -0.034722222         0
            95  2007-12-18 139.00 140.00 130.50 130.75 179600    107.97 110.84742 120.1938 121.8739 -0.059352518         0
            96  2007-12-19 130.50 131.00 128.00 129.25 231000    106.73 108.10247 119.3251 121.3774 -0.009578544         0
            97  2007-12-20 129.25 129.50 127.00 127.25 210800    105.08 106.08749 118.4061 120.8431 -0.015473888         0
            98  2007-12-21 127.25 128.50 126.50 126.75 112700    104.67 105.14250 117.5199 120.3128 -0.003929273         0
            99  2007-12-27 125.00 125.00 120.75 122.75 172300    101.37 102.62750 116.4780 119.6917 -0.018000000         0
            100 2007-12-28 122.50 122.50 117.00 117.00 396000     96.62  98.62250 115.1968 118.9353 -0.044897959         0
            101 2008-01-02 120.25 126.25 119.50 124.50 262600    102.81 101.41417 114.3977 118.4066  0.035343035         0
            102 2008-01-03 124.50 125.50 122.75 124.50  81300    102.81 102.34472 113.6501 117.8952  0.000000000         0
            103 2008-01-04 125.00 125.50 120.00 120.50  63400     99.51 100.45491 112.7378 117.2924 -0.036000000         0
            104 2008-01-07 121.00 123.50 117.00 123.25  52100    101.78 101.33830 112.0308 116.7838  0.018595041         0
            105 2008-01-08 123.75 125.50 123.25 124.25  53100    102.60 102.17943 111.4224 116.3188  0.004040404         0
            106 2008-01-09 123.75 123.75 119.25 121.00  42100     99.92 100.67314 110.6803 115.7811 -0.022222222         0
            107 2008-01-10 121.00 121.25 119.25 120.75  44500     99.71 100.03105 109.9725 115.2542 -0.002066116         0
            108 2008-01-11 120.00 123.25 120.00 123.25  49200    101.78 101.19702 109.4440 114.8124  0.027083333         0
            109 2008-01-14 121.50 125.50 121.50 125.50  48900    103.64 102.82567 109.0695 114.4461  0.032921811         0
            110 2008-01-15 125.75 125.75 122.00 122.00  58500    100.75 101.44189 108.5328 113.9971 -0.029821074         0
            111 2008-01-16 120.25 122.75 117.00 120.75  74800     99.71 100.28730 107.9636 113.5286  0.004158004         0
            112 2008-01-17 121.50 125.00 121.00 121.00  65400     99.92 100.04243 107.4446 113.0824 -0.004115226         0
            113 2008-01-18 121.50 121.50 117.75 118.00  55400     97.44  98.30748 106.7992 112.5696 -0.028806584         0
            114 2008-01-21 118.75 119.50 114.50 116.00  95200     95.79  96.62916 106.0889 112.0194 -0.023157895         0
            115 2008-01-22 114.50 121.25 112.50 120.00 158900     99.09  98.26972 105.6374 111.5955  0.048034934         0
            116 2008-01-23 120.50 121.75 116.25 119.25 142300     98.48  98.40991 105.1756 111.1655 -0.010373444         0
            117 2008-01-24 122.00 124.25 118.50 120.75  86800     99.71  99.27664 104.8230 110.7899 -0.010245902         0
            118 2008-01-25 122.00 122.00 118.50 120.50  76000     99.51  99.43221 104.4802 110.4201 -0.012295082         0
            119 2008-01-28 120.50 121.00 118.50 119.25  16500     98.48  98.79740 104.0931 110.0286 -0.010373444         0
            120 2008-01-29 124.00 124.00 121.50 122.50  29100    101.16 100.37247 103.9039 109.7378 -0.012096774         0
            121 2008-01-30 123.25 123.25 119.75 120.25  37300     99.30  99.65749 103.6068 109.3956 -0.024340771         0
            122 2008-01-31 122.00 122.00 118.00 120.25  25800     99.30  99.41916 103.3290 109.0646 -0.014344262         0
            123 2008-02-01 120.00 122.25 120.00 122.25  35800    100.95 100.43972 103.1755 108.7985  0.018750000         0
            124 2008-02-04 123.25 125.50 122.75 124.25  36700    102.60 101.87991 103.1384 108.5953  0.008113590         0
            125 2008-02-05 124.25 124.25 120.25 121.50  32700    100.33 100.84664 102.9572 108.3243 -0.022132797         0
            126 2008-02-06 120.00 121.75 116.00 118.00  46100     97.44  98.57555 102.6012 107.9675 -0.016666667         0
            127 2008-02-07 118.50 123.25 115.50 120.25  81600     99.30  99.05852 102.3883 107.6833  0.014767932         0
            128 2008-02-08 122.00 122.00 119.75 121.75  40200    100.54 100.04617 102.2690 107.4491 -0.002049180         0
            129 2008-02-11 120.00 122.50 119.00 122.50  43900    101.16 100.78872 102.1975 107.2429  0.020833333         0
            130 2008-02-12 123.00 123.00 120.50 120.75  29200     99.71 100.06957 102.0370 106.9959 -0.018292683         0
            131 2008-02-13 120.50 123.25 119.50 123.25  49400    101.78 101.20986 102.0204 106.8249  0.022821577         0
            132 2008-02-14 122.50 123.25 122.00 122.75  25000    101.37 101.31662 101.9784 106.6460  0.002040816         0
            133 2008-02-15 122.75 122.75 120.50 122.00  27100    100.75 100.93887 101.8992 106.4527 -0.006109980         0
            134 2008-02-18 122.75 122.75 121.00 121.25  26400    100.13 100.39962 101.7850 106.2454 -0.012219959         0
            135 2008-02-19 122.25 122.25 121.50 121.75  24300    100.54 100.49321 101.7047 106.0584 -0.004089980         0
            136 2008-02-20 121.75 124.25 120.00 122.50 115800    101.16 100.93774 101.6696 105.8978  0.006160164         0
            137 2008-02-21 126.00 143.00 126.00 140.00 316400    115.61 110.71925 102.5690 106.2162  0.111111111         0
            138 2008-02-22 139.00 145.50 138.75 144.25  50300    119.12 116.31975 103.6368 106.6393  0.037769784         0
            139 2008-02-25 146.00 149.25 146.00 148.50  88900    122.63 120.52658 104.8621 107.1635  0.017123288         0
            140 2008-02-26 150.00 156.00 150.00 154.00 134700    127.17 124.95553 106.3014 107.8195  0.026666667         0
            141 2008-02-27 155.50 155.50 146.50 151.00  33300    124.69 124.77851 107.4877 108.3726 -0.028938907         0
            142 2008-02-28 152.00 152.50 149.00 151.50  18200    125.11 124.99950 108.6246 108.9214 -0.003289474         0
            143 2008-02-29 151.50 155.50 146.00 154.00 148300    127.17 126.44650 109.8211 109.5197  0.016501650         0
            144 2008-03-03 152.50 155.50 151.00 154.50  43000    127.58 127.20217 110.9669 110.1119  0.013114754         0
            145 2008-03-04 156.00 161.50 154.00 157.00 163400    129.65 128.83406 112.1722 110.7524  0.006410256         0
            146 2008-03-05 157.00 158.00 154.50 156.00  90000    128.82 128.82469 113.2463 111.3448 -0.006369427         0
            147 2008-03-06 152.00 157.50 152.00 154.50  53200    127.58 127.99490 114.1710 111.8771  0.016447368         0
            148 2008-03-07 152.00 155.00 145.00 153.00 260900    126.35 126.89830 114.9568 112.3516  0.006578947         0
            149 2008-03-10 151.50 153.00 145.00 149.00  43200    123.04 124.32610 115.4783 112.7021 -0.016501650         0
            150 2008-03-11 147.00 152.00 141.00 150.00  35400    123.87 124.02203 116.0197 113.0682  0.020408163         0
            151 2008-03-12 151.00 151.00 148.50 148.50  39500    122.63 123.09401 116.4461 113.3817 -0.016556291         0
            152 2008-03-13 148.00 150.00 145.25 148.75 183500    122.84 122.92467 116.8586 113.6919  0.005067568         0
            153 2008-03-14 149.75 151.00 147.00 150.00  45000    123.87 123.55489 117.3110 114.0256  0.001669449         0
            154 2008-03-17 146.75 153.00 146.75 152.00  44100    125.52 124.86496 117.8406 114.4024  0.035775128         0
            155 2008-03-18 153.00 155.50 150.00 154.00  20600    127.17 126.40165 118.4425 114.8210  0.006535948         0
            156 2008-03-19 152.00 161.00 152.00 159.50  63500    131.71 129.94055 119.2985 115.3748  0.049342105         0
            157 2008-03-20 159.50 159.50 155.00 155.00  20200    128.00 128.64685 119.8599 115.7887 -0.028213166         0
            158 2008-03-25 157.00 163.50 154.00 160.00  36100    132.13 130.96895 120.6515 116.3245  0.019108280         0
            159 2008-03-26 158.00 160.00 154.00 155.50  22000    128.41 129.26298 121.1520 116.7207 -0.015822785         0
            160 2008-03-27 156.50 169.00 152.50 163.00  65700    134.60 132.82099 122.0196 117.3069  0.041533546         0
            161 2008-03-28 163.00 168.00 163.00 165.50  59400    136.67 135.38700 122.9648 117.9418  0.015337423         0
            162 2008-03-31 166.00 166.00 161.50 164.00  66100    135.43 135.41567 123.7690 118.5152 -0.012048193         0
            163 2008-04-01 163.00 172.50 163.00 171.50  71900    141.62 139.55189 124.9207 119.2727  0.052147239         0
            164 2008-04-02 171.00 177.00 170.50 174.00  98800    143.69 142.31063 126.1316 120.0733  0.017543860         0
            165 2008-04-03 173.50 178.00 171.00 173.00 100400    142.86 142.67688 127.2109 120.8204 -0.002881844         0
            166 2008-04-04 171.00 171.00 161.50 163.00 397500    134.60 137.29229 127.6876 121.2722 -0.046783626         0
            167 2008-04-07 173.50 178.00 157.50 173.00 133600    142.86 141.00410 128.6665 121.9800 -0.002881844         0
            168 2008-04-08 158.50 159.50 152.50 155.00  52400    128.00 132.33470 128.6235 122.1774 -0.022082019         0
            169 2008-04-09 152.00 157.50 151.50 157.00 297400    129.65 130.54490 128.6897 122.4224  0.032894737         0
            170 2008-04-10 156.00 158.50 155.50 157.00 119500    129.65 129.94830 128.7516 122.6593  0.006410256         0
            171 2008-04-11 157.50 159.00 154.50 156.50  45700    129.24 129.47610 128.7832 122.8751 -0.006349206         0
            172 2008-04-14 154.50 157.00 152.00 155.50  47600    128.41 128.76537 128.7591 123.0566  0.006472492         0
            173 2008-04-15 157.00 158.50 155.00 157.50  12700    130.06 129.62846 128.8430 123.2862  0.003184713         0
            174 2008-04-16 159.00 159.00 154.50 156.50  14000    129.24 129.36949 128.8686 123.4814 -0.015723270         0
            175 2008-04-17 158.50 159.00 156.50 158.00  47100    130.47 130.10316 128.9719 123.7105 -0.003154574         0
            176 2008-04-18 157.00 159.00 157.00 158.50  15800    130.89 130.62772 129.0957 123.9459  0.009554140         0
            177 2008-04-21 159.00 159.00 157.50 158.50  37200    130.89 130.80257 129.2114 124.1736 -0.003144654         0
            178 2008-04-22 159.00 160.00 153.50 156.50 136900    129.24 129.76086 129.2133 124.3397 -0.015723270         0
            179 2008-04-23 157.00 160.00 153.50 158.00  31100    130.47 130.23362 129.2944 124.5407  0.006369427         0
            180 2008-04-24 158.00 162.00 158.00 161.50 121000    133.36 132.31787 129.5567 124.8299  0.022151899         0
            181 2008-04-25 161.50 170.00 160.50 169.50  54200    139.97 137.41929 130.2285 125.3263  0.049535604         0
            182 2008-04-28 168.50 170.00 165.50 167.50  31100    138.32 138.01976 130.7505 125.7523 -0.005934718         1
            183 2008-04-29 170.00 171.50 167.00 171.00  78700    141.21 140.14659 131.4253 126.2591  0.005882353         1
            184 2008-04-30 170.00 174.00 168.50 170.50  23000    140.80 140.58220 132.0301 126.7358  0.002941176         1
            185 2008-05-02 171.50 177.00 171.00 176.50  39100    145.75 144.02740 132.9153 127.3593  0.029154519         1
            186 2008-05-05 173.50 177.50 171.00 172.00   7000    142.04 142.70247 133.5040 127.8406 -0.008645533         1
            187 2008-05-06 170.00 173.00 169.00 173.00  27800    142.86 142.80749 134.1076 128.3330  0.017647059         1
            188 2008-05-07 171.50 177.00 171.50 176.00  44000    145.34 144.49583 134.8323 128.8906  0.026239067         1
            189 2008-05-08 174.50 178.50 173.50 178.50  64600    147.40 146.43194 135.6431 129.4975  0.022922636         1
            190 2008-05-09 177.50 179.00 174.50 178.00  22600    146.99 146.80398 136.3752 130.0710  0.002816901         1
            191 2008-05-12 175.00 178.00 175.00 176.00   9700    145.34 145.82799 136.9535 130.5716  0.005714286         1
            192 2008-05-13 176.00 179.50 176.00 179.50  22400    148.23 147.42933 137.6810 131.1506  0.019886364         1
            193 2008-05-14 178.50 181.50 178.00 181.50  31800    149.88 149.06311 138.4681 131.7647  0.016806723         1
            194 2008-05-15 182.00 183.50 181.00 183.50  49400    151.53 150.70770 139.3108 132.4127  0.008241758         1
            195 2008-05-16 184.00 184.50 183.00 183.50  29300    151.53 151.25590 140.0991 133.0395 -0.002717391         1
            196 2008-05-19 183.00 183.00 179.00 180.00 106000    148.64 149.51197 140.6501 133.5510 -0.016393443         1
            197 2008-05-20 177.00 177.00 175.00 176.00  30600    145.34 146.73066 140.9527 133.9375 -0.005649718         1
            198 2008-05-21 176.00 182.00 173.00 173.50 110700    143.27 144.42355 141.1022 134.2435 -0.014204545         1
            199 2008-05-22 173.50 173.50 168.00 168.00 111400    142.01 142.81452 141.1608 134.4982 -0.031700288         1
            200 2008-05-23 170.00 170.00 164.00 165.50  63600    139.89 140.86484 141.0788 134.6749 -0.026470588
         0
```

Comment: replacing with '[[' does not solve the issue. Also, why would it? I'm only familiar with [[ from lists, could you elaborate?

Comment: @uncool, as a side note `data.frame` inherits from `list`, http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html, which is why `[[` works for both classes